# Which of SQLite or sharedpreferences is better for a registration system in an Android application?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sharedpreferences

I'm in the process of developing a application and I wanted to know if its better to use sharedpreferences to create a login, register and also logout functionality in Android Studio app instead of using Sqlite?

I am new to Android development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About that its totally on your choice what you use to save the current state of user , i will prefer using shared preferences. And for signup and sign in use SQLite database. Shared preferences are commonly used to perform light operations. You can search through data in SQLite as you may have many users.

So use SQLite to register and login and then use shared preferences to save tha current state of user.

**Shared Prefences**

sharedPreferences is a key/value store where you can save a data under certain key. To read the data from the store you have to know the key of the data. This makes reading the data very easy. But as easy as it is to store a small amount of data as difficult it is to store and read large structured data as you need to define key for every single data.

Comment: I am not an Android dev, but I am reasonably familiar with the concepts. When discussing SQLite in the context of Android, don't we generally mean an on-device database? If so, how would that aid a login system - doesn't a registered user system need to contact a remote sign-in server in order to check passwords, change passwords, pick usernames, etc?

Comment: @halfer Yess , both can be done, when your app is an offline app and you want it to be password protected then you can use your local SQLite to save user credentials.. And when we have an online system then we use Web Services for maintaining user record :) Hope it satisfied you

Comment: Ah yes Abdul, very interesting, thanks. Presumably one has to take into account the security level required when logging in offline, given that if a device is stolen, the password hashes could just be overwritten via direct access to the filing system, changing it to a value known to the attacker. And care should be taken not to give access to online/remote data based on a successful offline authentication?

Comment: @halfer Yes exactly. And think of a scenario where you have like gallery app, which donot need any online connection and you also want it to be protected so use local DB instead of online services :)